# In my EasyMock I have an error from an object inside the test class's method

Tags: testng, powermock, easymock

Given the code

```
@Test
public void testXClass(){
    XClass xclass = new XClass();
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = EasyMock.createMock(UriBuilder.class);
    EasyMock.expect(uriBuilder.fromUri(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class))).andReturn(dummyUriBuilder()).anyTimes();
    //EasyMock.replay(uriBuilder);
    EasyMock.expect(xclass.xMethod(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class))).andReturn("Done").anyTimes();
    String x  = xclass.xMethod(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class));
}

private UriBuilder dummyUriBuilder() {
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri("https://dev.x-service.com");
    uriBuilder.path("/x1/");
    return uriBuilder;
}

class XClass {

    public String xMethod(String x) {
        ...
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri("https://dev.x-service.com");
        uriBuilder.path("/x1/");
        ...
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri("https://dev.x-service.com");
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.UriBuilderImpl.uri(UriBuilderImpl.java:888) at
  javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
```

How do I mock this `UriBuilder` stuff? I think I am doing it wrong in setting the EasyMock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the static method `UriBuilder.fromUri`. This cannot be done with EasyMock. You need [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) for this.

Comment: Thank you, I added this after you suggested,  PowerMock.mockStatic(UriBuilder.class);
  EasyMock.expect(UriBuilder.fromUri(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class))).andReturn(dummyUriBuilder());
  PowerMock.replay(UriBuilder.class); Getting the same error

Comment: Do you use the `PowerMockRule` (or the `PowerMockRunner`) : https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule

Comment: PowerMockRule and PowerMockRunner are with JUnit, I am using TestNg, my test case extends org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase